# Extract elements from list of strings that match regex

Tags: python

I have a list of a lot of elements:

```
l = ['tribunavtplus.client.db.PagingResultSet/2610158785',
'java.util.ArrayList/4159755760',
'tribunavtplus.client.db.ERGEBNISSTORE/3664619045',
'605',
'I. Sozialversicherungsgerichtshof',
'',
'a514394f9f18429995d4cd5c64fbc6de',
'Arrêt de la Ie Cour des assurances sociales du Tribunal cantonal',
'605 2022 1',
'3a4604ff7f9b404193346990b98f7179',
'605 2021 234',
'Assurance-accidents, rente (capacité de travail, revenus retenus dans le calcul du taux d\\x27invalidité, exigibilité), atteinte à l\\x27intégrité.',
'608',
'D:\\\\InetPubData\\\\PublicationDocuments\\\\80749472d88e4d45a0d3c340acbb670a.pdf',
'Polizeirichter Greyerz',
'D:\\\\InetPubData\\\\PublicationDocuments\\\\412d9325978b487f8b15a13380ba4436.pdf',
'Assurance-invalidité (refus de rente et de mesures d\\x27ordre professionnel).',
'101',
'I. Zivilappellationshof',
'c321e55aa536438fb95a06eb798eff82',
'Arrêt de la Ie Cour d\\x27appel civil du Tribunal cantonal',
'101 2022 202',
'2022-09-16',
'D:\\\\InetPubData\\\\PublicationDocuments\\\\c321e55aa536438fb95a06eb798eff82.pdf',
'Eheschutzmassnahmen',
'Gericht Saane',
'Mesures protectrices de l\\x27union conjugale, droit de visite, contributions d\\x27entretien.',
'603',
'III. Verwaltungsgerichtshof',
'3a801995f04b48948c0d1d2224b8f4b9',
'Arrêt de la IIIe Cour administrative du Tribunal cantonal',
'603 2022 110',
'D:\\\\InetPubData\\\\PublicationDocuments\\\\3a801995f04b48948c0d1d2224b8f4b9.pdf',
'Strassenverkehr und Transportwesen',
'Amt für Strassenverkehr und Schifffahrt (ASS)',
'502 2022 24',
'2022-09-22',
'D:\\\\InetPubData\\\\PublicationDocuments\\\\d2c0687313f24491870571dcfd64d6ad.pdf',
'102',
'java.lang.Boolean/476441737']
```

I want to extract elements such as:

```
'101 2022 202'
'502 2022 24'
'605 2022 1'
```

etc.

So blocks of 3 nubers between 1 and 4 digits with a space inside.
I have tried this, but It does not work:

```
regex_id = re.compile(r"(\d{1,5})(\s)(\d{1,5})(\s)(\d{1,5})")
id_list = [value for value in l if regex_id.search(str(value))==True]
print(id_list)
```

But I always get empty list

Comment: change `id_list = [value for value in l if regex_id.search(str(value))==True]` to `id_list = [value for value in l if regex_id.search(str(value))]` and it should work

Comment: Right.  As a general rule, NEVER write `x==True` or `x==False` in Python. Instead, just use `x` or `not x`.